# How do I call pendingIntent just before setting AlarmManager for it

Tags: android, android-widget, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have this widget, that updates in second or minute intervals.

After adding widget to screen PreferencesActivity is launched, when user decides that everything is set up properly he exits settings and I'm calling method:

```
public class MyWidgetConfiguration extends PreferenceActivity {
    // [...] Some code...

    private void createWidget() {
        Context c = getApplicationContext() ;
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences( PREF_NAME+widgetID, MODE_PRIVATE );

        // Set layout
        AppWidgetManager awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance( c );
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews( c.getPackageName(), LAYOUT_ID );

        awm.updateAppWidget( widgetID, rv );

        // start alarm manager running this particular widget
        Intent i = new Intent( c, MyWidgetReceiver.class );
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( c, 0, i, 0 );
        AlarmManager a = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE );

        /** 
         * MY GUESS IS, THAT I'D HAVE TO ADD SOME KIND OF PendingIntent CALL HERE,
         * I TRIED COUPLE OF THINGS, BUT MOST OF THEM INTERFERED OR CANCELLED FOLLOWING 
         * AlarmManager REPEATING... 
         *
         * DELAY contains time left to closest full minute 
         */
        a.setRepeating( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + DELAY, MINUTE, pi );     

        /// return widget ID
        Intent resultValue = new Intent();
        resultValue.putExtra( AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetID );
        setResult( RESULT_OK, resultValue );

        finish();
    }

    // [...] More of some code...
}
```

So, as you see above, I'm calling alarmManager each minute from the first full minute, and everything works fine AFTER delay passes, but before that my widget is kinda frozen for some time. I'd like to prevent this, but without adding any additional logic to Receiver, since it can be called even each second. Full & original code here: http://goo.gl/uOP9P

Answer (score 0):

The PendingIntent is probably going to call some code written somewhere else. Why don't you call that same code directly after setting the alarm?